# error rtrim() in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php

Tags: laravel

/*When I try to view the output of my project on the browser, I am redirected to the following error

> "ErrorException (E_WARNING)rtrim () expects the parameter 1 to be
>   string, given the object ".

Can someone help me?

*/
    i find the problem in following function `public function setBasePath($basePath ){`
    below the code `Application.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation;

use Closure;
use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel as HttpKernelContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as SymfonyRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application as ApplicationContract;

class Application extends Container implements ApplicationContract, HttpKernelInterface
{
    /**
     * The Laravel framework version.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const VERSION = '5.6.39';

    /**
     * The base path for the Laravel installation.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Indicates if the application has been bootstrapped before.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $hasBeenBootstrapped = false;

    /**
     * Indicates if the application has "booted".
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $booted = false;

    /**
     * The array of booting callbacks.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $bootingCallbacks = [];

    /**
     * The array of booted callbacks.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $bootedCallbacks = [];

    /**
     * The array of terminating callbacks.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $terminatingCallbacks = [];

    /**
     * All of the registered service providers.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $serviceProviders = [];

    /**
     * The names of the loaded service providers.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedProviders = [];

    /**
     * The deferred services and their providers.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $deferredServices = [];

    /**
     * The custom database path defined by the developer.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $databasePath;

    /**
     * The custom storage path defined by the developer.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $storagePath;

    /**
     * The custom environment path defined by the developer.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $environmentPath;

    /**
     * The environment file to load during bootstrapping.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $environmentFile = '.env';

    /**
     * The application namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace;

    /**
     * Create a new Illuminate application instance.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $basePath
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($basePath = null)
    {
        if ($basePath) {
            $this->setBasePath($basePath);
        }

        $this->registerBaseBindings();

        $this->registerBaseServiceProviders();

        $this->registerCoreContainerAliases();
    }

    /**
     * Get the version number of the application.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function version()
    {
        return static::VERSION;
    }

    /**
     * Register the basic bindings into the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerBaseBindings()
    {
        static::setInstance($this);

        $this->instance('app', $this);

        $this->instance(Container::class, $this);

        $this->instance(PackageManifest::class, new PackageManifest(
            new Filesystem, $this->basePath(), $this->getCachedPackagesPath()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Register all of the base service providers.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerBaseServiceProviders()
    {
        $this->register(new EventServiceProvider($this));

        $this->register(new LogServiceProvider($this));

        $this->register(new RoutingServiceProvider($this));
    }

    /**
     * Run the given array of bootstrap classes.
     *
     * @param  array  $bootstrappers
     * @return void
     */
    public function bootstrapWith(array $bootstrappers)
    {
        $this->hasBeenBootstrapped = true;

        foreach ($bootstrappers as $bootstrapper) {
            $this['events']->fire('bootstrapping: '.$bootstrapper, [$this]);

            $this->make($bootstrapper)->bootstrap($this);

            $this['events']->fire('bootstrapped: '.$bootstrapper, [$this]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to run after loading the environment.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public function afterLoadingEnvironment(Closure $callback)
    {
        return $this->afterBootstrapping(
            LoadEnvironmentVariables::class, $callback
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to run before a bootstrapper.
     *
     * @param  string  $bootstrapper
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeBootstrapping($bootstrapper, Closure $callback)
    {
        $this['events']->listen('bootstrapping: '.$bootstrapper, $callback);
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to run after a bootstrapper.
     *
     * @param  string  $bootstrapper
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public function afterBootstrapping($bootstrapper, Closure $callback)
    {
        $this['events']->listen('bootstrapped: '.$bootstrapper, $callback);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the application has been bootstrapped before.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasBeenBootstrapped()
    {
        return $this->hasBeenBootstrapped;
    }

    /**
     * Set the base path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $basePath
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath )
    {
        $this->basePath = rtrim($basePath, '\/');

        $this->bindPathsInContainer();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Bind all of the application paths in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function bindPathsInContainer()
    {
        $this->instance('path', $this->path());
        $this->instance('path.base', $this->basePath());
        $this->instance('path.lang', $this->langPath());
        $this->instance('path.config', $this->configPath());
        $this->instance('path.public', $this->publicPath());
        $this->instance('path.storage', $this->storagePath());
        $this->instance('path.database', $this->databasePath());
        $this->instance('path.resources', $this->resourcePath());
        $this->instance('path.bootstrap', $this->bootstrapPath());
    }

    /**
     * Get the path to the application "app" directory.
     *
     * @param  string  $path Optionally, a path to append to the app path
     * @return string
     */
    public function path($path = '')
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'app'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }

    /**
     * Get the base path of the Laravel installation.
     *
     * @param  string  $path Optionally, a path to append to the base path
     * @return string
     */
    public function basePath($path = '')
    {
        return $this->basePath.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path to the bootstrap directory.
     *
     * @param  string  $path Optionally, a path to append to the bootstrap path
     * @return string
     */
    public function bootstrapPath($path = '')
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'bootstrap'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path to the application configuration files.
     *
     * @param  string  $path Optionally, a path to append to the config path
     * @return string
     */
    public function configPath($path = '')
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path to the database directory.
     *
     * @param  string  $path Optionally, a path to append to the database path
     * @return string
     */
    public function databasePath($path = '')
    {
        return ($this->databasePath ?: $thi`enter code here`s->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'database').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check you .env for APP_BASE_PATH?

The Application is initialized in bootstrap/app.php file

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

As you can see it looks `APP_BASE_PATH` environment variable and if this is not set it uses the path to your root application folder.

`dirname(__DIR__)` returns the path to the parent folder.

Based on the details you posted it looks like the problem can be with the value you set for `APP_BASE_PATH`

This response assumes you are using the latest version of Laravel, 5.8

Comment: It return the same problem.I add this in the app.php code:

Comment: $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

Comment: Be more explicit please. Is `APP_BASE_PATH ` set in your .env file? If so, what's the value in there?

Can you please post your complete .env file, after you make sure you remove any sensitive data?

Comment: this is the value of my APP_BASE_PATH in the file .env: APP_BASE_PATH=C:/xampp/htdocs/blog

Comment: Ok, what's with the `-` at the end? Can you remove that and the space before the - and see if it works?

Comment: Try one of the following: 

1. Remove the line completely, and see if what error do you get, if any.
2. Set the path as follow APP_BASE_PATH=C:\xampp\htdocs\blog

Comment: both with and without the line "APP_BASE_PATH = C:\xampp\htdocs\blog" returns the same error: "rtrim () expects the parameter 1 to be string, given object" in the Application.php file